# sed replace empty line with character

Tags: bash, sed, awk

How do you replace a blank line in a file with a certain character using sed?

I have used the following command but it still returns the original input:

```
sed 's/^$/>/' filename
```

Original input:

```
ACTCTATCATC

CTACTATCTATCC

CCATCATCTACTC

...
```

Desired output:

```
ACTCTATCATC
>
CTACTATCTATCC
>
CCATCATCTACTC
>
...
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: do you have whitespace on your blank lines? Your command works for me

Comment: Yes, that ended up being the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way with `awk`. This wouldn't care if you have spaces or blank lines:

```
awk '!NF{$0=">"}1' file
```

`NF` stands for number of fields. Since blank lines or lines with just spaces have no fields, we use that to insert your text. `1` triggers the condition to be `true` and prints the line:

**Test:**

```
$ cat -vet file
ACTCTATCATC$
      $
CTACTATCTATCC$
$
CCATCATCTACTC$
       $
```

*`$` are end of line markers*

```
$ awk '!NF{$0=">"}1' file
ACTCTATCATC
>
CTACTATCTATCC
>
CCATCATCTACTC
>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Awk works nicely. Is awk less picky than sed?

Comment: @cebach561 You're welcome. Diplomatically, I would say it's just more flexible than `sed`. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

You may have tabs or white spaces in your `filename`' empty lines, try the following:

```
sed 's/^\s*$/>/' filename
```

Comment: For some reason that command doesn't convert blanks to >. Both Raman Shah and jay pal's answers worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `\s` is a Perl regex extension which is supported by some `sed` variants, but definitely not portable or recommended.

Answer (score 2):

You may have whitespace in your input. First thing to try is:

```
sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*$/>/' filename
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you very much. Could you explain what you mean by whitespace in the input?

Comment: The issue is that your "blank" lines may actually have spacebars or tabs in them, and sed can see these and won't match on `^$`. Given that my suggestion worked, I am confident that this was the case.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work:

```
sed -i  's/^[[:space:]]*$/string/' foo
```

Answer (score 0):

What's missing here is the escape character. This will work for you.

```
sed 's/^$/\>/g' filename
```

And if you need to delete the empty lines and print others, Try

```
sed '/^$/d' filename
```