# sed replace # with empty line

Tags: sed

How do you replace a line that only has # with an empty line using sed?

I have tried to find on google but I haven't gotten anything.

File Content:

```
#test
another test
#
another test2
```

Expected result:

```
#test
another test

another test2
```

So, under expected result, after another test the line should be blank without the #.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: This might help: [sed replace empty line with character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22263664/3776858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regular expressions you can match for the beginning of a line with `^` and the end of a line with `$`.  The `s/regexp/replacement/` command will replace text that matches `regexp` with `replacement`.

This `sed` command gives the desired output:
`sed 's/^#$//' < input.txt`

On each line, `sed` looks for the start of a line, a `#` character, and then the end of a line, and replaces it with nothing.  The newline character remains, however, so you are left with a blank line.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/^#$//'
```

- Anchor to beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of line to match a whole line exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/[[:alnum:]]/ ! s/#//' file
#test
another test

another test2
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^#$/g' file
```

If a line contains only `#`, replace it by a blank line.

Alternatives:

```
sed 's/^#$//' file
```

or

```
sed '/^#$/c\\' file
```